# Can anyone tell me why my field calculator is returning this error?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, field-calculator, error-000539

All I am trying to do is pull into a text field, a section of another text field via:

fieldB = !fieldA![some_index:other_index]

However I keep receiving the error below and I can't figure out why. My python syntax is correct and I have tried it in IDLE on an example string with the exact contents of a row in my feature class and it works fine.

I am using ArcGIS 10.0. The error is:

```
Executing: CalculateField AA_TCPs_Complete_060613 Cross_rd_1 !PopupInfo![5:10] PYTHON_9.3 #
Start Time: Fri Jun 07 13:31:03 2013
ERROR 000539: <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>:invalid syntax(<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Fri Jun 07 13:31:03 2013 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Comment: do you have the python radio checked?

Comment: Is PopupInfo a text field? If it's numeric, I can see that causing the syntax error.

Comment: @ Brad: yes python radio is checked.

Comment: @ Jason: yes PopupInfo field is a text field, as is the destination field.

Comment: You said in your question that you are using 10.0.  Why is the code error referencing `PYTHON_9.3`?  Are you running this from ArcToolbox?  Do you have any NULL data values, or data values < 11 characters long that may be causing it to bomb out?  Can you post an image of your Field Calculator window?

Comment: Another thought, do you have any [quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675695/python-removing-double-quotation-marks-so-that-script-runs), exclamation points, or other special characters in your data that it might be getting confused with?

Comment: I have hmtl tags in the field. Are theses restricted characters?

Comment: These are my options when using python expressions in the field calculator:PYTHON—The expression will be written in a standard Python format. Use of geoprocessor methods and properties is the same as creating a 9.2 version geoprocessor. 
PYTHON_9.3—The expression will be written in a standard Python format. Use of geoprocessor methods and properties is the same as creating a 9.3 version geoprocessor.

Comment: field names are not very good at handling special characters, so your html tags might be a problem. Especially if you are using a gdb and not a shapefile, in my experience. Also, Python_9.3 is the option you should use for this. 
If I were you I'd try to make new fields with only a-z in the field name and try again!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I am in fact editing a feature class. I'll export it as shp first and see if that helps.

Comment: Your example works fine for me at 10.1 SP1 - I used TestField = !admin![0:3] on a file geodatabase feature class in the Field Calculator.  However, I notice that you seem to be using the Calculate Field tool instead so I will try it that way to see if that breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax, that I just copied as a Python snippet from Geoprocessing | Results after running the Calculate Field tool, then worked fine from the Python window too.  I used ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 but I would expect it to work at 10.0 equally well.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Countries","TestField","!admin![0:3]","PYTHON_9.3","#")
```

If you are still having problems with this perhaps you can post (via an edit to your Question) exactly where you are using your syntax.

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to say that you can't access fieldA by index like that in Field Calculator. Might be wrong. Anyway, you could try it in VB: fieldB = Left([fieldA], 5), for example.

Or, try !fieldA[index1:index2]!

Comment: You would be wrong about your Python comment.  The syntax works just fine for me in 10.0.

Comment: Well, that's why I said it might be wrong. In that case, why doesn't it work for the poster?